# Sikuli Image differentiaton

Tags: button, click, sikuli

I have a case where there is an OK button on two windows. I want to click the OK button on the former window but using Sikuli I am unable to do it. I tried using Python script getting the nearest button using Y co-ordinates. But I guess its not working.

Comment: A bit more information will be very helpful. There are 2 answers and no comments\updates..

Answer (score 0):

Find something that's in the window you're interested in but not in the other (e.g. part of the title), extend the matched area to contain the button you want but not the other one, then search for the button within that area.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "it's not working". How far have you got? What result do you get? Edit your question to show the code you've used so far.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options come to mind:

1. Restrict your search to a particular area of the screen either by pre-defining a region, (region.click(okButton1), or
2. you can try using sorted() to sort the y coordinates (if they appear left-and-right of each other) or x coordinates (if they appear above-and-below each other) of the two OK buttons, and then click on the one of interest like so--

   ```
   #to find top-most OK Button
   def byY(match):
       return match.y

   okButtons = list([x for x in findAll(OkButtonPic)]) #make a list of the OK Buttons
   TopOkButton = sorted(okButtons, key=byY)[0] #sort them according to Y values
   click(topOkButton)

   #to find left-most OK button
   def byX(match):
       return match.x

   okButtons = list([x for x in findAll(OkButtonPic)])
   leftOkButton = sorted(okButtons, key=byX)[0]
   click(leftOkButton)
   ```
3. If there is anything distinct that reliably appears near the OK button that you want to click, you can click(uniqueThing).targetOffset(pixelsX,pixelsY).

If the OK button you want to click is in a window that is now covered, there are other issues to deal with, making the window visible first, but that's not what it sounds like your question is really asking...